# How to find out which Eclipse Validator caused a warning?

Tags: eclipse

The Eclipse project I just imported has a lot of warnings (and even errors) and I want to find out from which validation component they are. Short of clicking through all the warnings and errors, is there a way to get quickly from the warning to the preferences so I can change them?

[image]

Here is an example. It just says "Validation Message". How can I find the location in the preferences to disable this and make it a warning instead?

Clarification: I am looking for a general solution not this one in particular. I want to be able to configure the warning level of each issue as I work through the issues. Not by clicking through preferences until I hit the right preference.

Comment: This should indicate the problem type, which is named too general here. What exactly is the _Validation Message_ and where was it found (file type/extension)?

Comment: I am looking for a general solution, because I feel something like that has to exist. There is way more than one issue that I want to either set to warning/info/ignore...  this particular one is from a file ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml and the error says it cannot find a certain binding for this EJB. As I said this is just an example. I suppose one valid answer could be: there is no general way to get from the error message to the preference where you can turn it into a warning. That would not be the desired outcome however.

Comment: For Java problems, there are _Configure problem serverity_ Quick Fixes (Ctrl+1) for that. But in your case, there are no Quick Fixes at all, as you can see from the missing light bulb. You can report this as a feature request.

Comment: Actually that is the answer I am looking for. And now that you said it I have done that previously for java issues. So the answer is: there is a way but only for some problems. Would you post it as an answer? Also sadly none of the issues I need to get "rid off" has quick fixes... which is just too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example for Java problems, there are ***Configure problem serverity* Quick Fixes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) for that**.

Unfortunately, **in your case, there are no Quick Fixes** at all, as you can see from the missing light bulb. Also, the type *"Validation Message"* is too general to be helpful here. Here only the error message and the type/extension of the file containing the error give hints where the validator can be deactivated.

Please report this as a feature request to Eclipse if it hasn't been done yet.